# NDK for AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I follow this page to study "NDK setting under androidStudio".

http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/

But I face an issue when I Config ndk with gradle.here is error message.
have anybody help me?

Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ndk()'
Possible causes:

The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: which version of gradle android plugin are you using ? you have to use at least version 0.7.3 (that is already one year old) and the ndk {} block has to be under defaultConfig: `android { defaultConfig { ndk {} } }`

Comment: @ph0b Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it by following the steps in this blog:
http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/

and looking at the source code of this project:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

I hope that helps.