# Is there any way to specify gradle version when cordova creates android project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I am using latest Cordova 5.4.0 and when I perform 'cordova platform add android' cordova creates gradle.build for gradle 2.1.1. I need to implement some JNI C++ code for android plugin, but this version doesn't support NDK well and I can't add NDK related section to the build file to introduce NDK support and set module name. Adding such section causes build errors (Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'ndk()')

According to this manual http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/ I am trying to add following section

```
android.ndk {
   moduleName = "mymodule"
}
```

So, is there any way to force cordova to generate gradle.build for fresh gradle version like 2.8 or 2.9 ? Just changing gradle version in the build file from 2.2.1 to 2.8 doesnt work because there is new 'model' root namespace and probably other changes required.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is impossible at the moment. The best way to integrate cpp code to cordova android project is create separate JNI project, build libs for all possible platforms using ndk-build and integrate libs to your plugin in plugin.xml this way

Btw, it makes impossible debugging C++ code from Cordova project using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385090/ndk-for-androidstudio) helped but had to change a few things.

Here are the steps that fixed it for me.

Create `gradle.properties` (if it doesn't already exist) in the root folder of your app (where `AndroidManifest.xml` is)

Add the following line to it:

`android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`

In your build.gradle file, add "ndk" block under the `android { defaultConfig { ... } }`

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            moduleName "native"
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to change your gradleVersion if Android Studio prompts you to.

Rebuild your project and it should compile.

Comment: It should be noted that the line `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` was fixed in [Cordova Android 5.1.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/01/24/cordova-android-5.1.0.html)